# Error using vertcat in MatLab

Tags: matlab

im getting a vertcat error in my for loop, i have looked about for a solution but i cant seem to find one that has a matrix in the loop. It also appears to solve the loop once then get stuck the second time round. this is my code:
the error is at matrix A, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
phi=1:1:89;
for i=1:length(phi)

m=cosd(phi(1:i));
l=sind(phi(1:i));
%the following calculates k tilde ratio for use in solving of equations
r= U1/U2; %velocity ratio
Kratio = ((r*(mach2/(1-mach2^2)))*(-m*mach2 + l*sqrt((m.^2/l.^2)-(((1/r)^2)*
((1/mach2^2)-1)))));
alpha = (A2^2/(gamma*U1^2))*(Kratio/(m-(Kratio*(1/r))));
beta= (A2^2/(gamma*U1^2))*(l/(m-(Kratio*(1/r))));

%from boundary conditions 
B1= (((gamma-1)*(mach1^2))-2)/((gamma+1)*(mach1^2));
B2= 2/((gamma+1)*mach1^2);
C1=4/(((gamma-1)*mach1^2)+2);
C2= -(((gamma-1)*mach1^2)+4)/(((gamma-1)*mach1^2)+2);
D1= (4*gamma*mach1^2)/((2*gamma*mach1^2)-(gamma-1));
D2=-((2*gamma*mach1^2)/((2*gamma*mach1^2)-(gamma-1)));
E1= (2*(mach1^2-1))/((gamma+1)*mach1^2);

%matrix to be solved for unknown coefficients

matrixA= [1 0 0 -alpha 0 0 0; 0 ((m*r)) 0 0 l 0 0; 0 0 1 -beta 0 0 0; 1 1 0 0 0     
(B1-1) 0; 0 0 0 1/gamma 0 C1 1; 0 0 0 1 0 D1 0; 0 0 1 0 1 ((E1*l)/m) 0];-->error here

matrixB= [0 ; 0 ; 0 ; -B2*Ae+B1*l*Av ; C1*l*Av-C2*Ae ; D1*l*Av-D2*Ae; -m*Av];

format long
coefficients= matrixA\matrixB;

i=sqrt(-1);
t=0;

F=coefficients(1,1);
G=coefficients(2,1);
H=coefficients(3,1);
K=coefficients(4,1);
I=coefficients(5,1);
L=coefficients(6,1);
Q=coefficients(7,1);

% assumes k=1 for equation Kratio,t=0 for this case (test)
%N=201;
%x=zeros(N);
%for j=1:N
x=20;
x1=-20;
%end
%for j=1:N
y=0;
y2=0;



%upstream and downstream conditions
%plots the graph for fixed t
% k has been set to 2
 %entropy modes




%vorticity modes

%plot for upstream KE 
u1prime= l*Av*exp(k*i*(m*x1+l*y2-U1*m*t));
v1prime= -m*Av*exp(k*i*(m*x1+l*y2-U1*m*t));
KE1= u1prime.*conj(u1prime)+v1prime.*conj(v1prime);


%plot for downstream KE (kinetic engery)
u2prime2=F*exp(k*i*Kratio*x+k*i*l*y-k*i*U1*m*t)+G*exp((k*i*(m*r*x+l*y-U1*m*t)));
v2prime2=H*exp(k*i*Kratio*x+k*i*l*y-k*i*U1*m*t)+I*exp((k*i*(m*r*x+l*y-U1*m*t)));
KE=u2prime2.*conj(u2prime2)+v2prime2.*conj(v2prime2);

KEnorm=(KE)/KE1


end
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint at that line, then check the sizes of all the variables. One of them isn't a scalar. i.e. check `alpha`, `((m*r))` etc...

Comment: thanks for replying so quickly, i will try that and let you know how it goes

Comment: Not a good idea to use i as the iterator and definitely not when using "i=sqrt(-1);" inside the loop!

Comment: damn completely blanked that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from `(m*r)` (and another one will arise with `l` in `matrixB`).
`m` and `l` grow inside the loop:

```
m=cosd(phi(1:i));  
l=sind(phi(1:i));
```

It's up to you to figure out which portion of `m` and `l` you want to use after the first iteration.
As Dan pointed out, the route to debug this is to set a [`breakpoint`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) in the line that gives the error. Once you get to it, check all the variables in your matrix for their size.

---

One last comment: I had to assume the following variables:

```
U1 = 1.0;
U2 = 0.5;
mach2 = 0.3;
mach1 = 0.5;
A2 = 0.6;
gamma = 1.4;
Ae = 1;
Av = 1;
k = 1;
```

Next time, please consider providing a minimal working example, that upon copy/paste will regenerate your problem.

---

**EDIT**
If you attempt to fix your code, consider the following steps:

1. As Divakar suggested, do not use `i` as the loop counter, when you need it as the imaginary unit. Therefore, replace all instances of the loop counter with `ii` (take your time doing this, you do not want to overlook one instance).
2. Next, you have two choices:

   - **either**, replace `m` and `l` with this:

     ```
     m=cosd(phi(ii));  
     l=sind(phi(ii));
     ```

     that way, both `m` and `l` will remain scalars
   - **or**, replace every instance of `m` and `l` with `m(ii)` and `l(ii)` respectively

   whichever you do, be consistent.

Comment: it was thank you, although i dont think im quite good enough at this to fix it.